# Convert guava multi map values into a list

Tags: java, list, hashmap, guava, multimap

I want to convert a

```
 Multimap<Foo1, Foo2> into a Map<Foo1, List<Foo2>>.
```

What is the best way to do this?
Note I am referring to Google Guava's multimap here.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you already have a `ListMultimap`, or just a `Multimap`?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Multimaps::asMap](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#asMap-com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap-)